# Is there any book dealing with the history of both astronomy and geometry?

Tags: astronomy, geometry, book-recommendation

I am preparing an introductory course on the history of astronomy and geometry for intermediate students. The intention is to teach Copernican heliocentrism, Kepler's laws of planetary motion & Newton's law of universal gravitation. I couldn't find any single book dealing with both subjects. I am wondering:  is there any such book?

Comment: The term "intermediate students" is not very informative without more context. What ages are the students, and what math background and physics background are the students assumed to have? High school algebra and trigonometry but not calculus? Elementary calculus but not cookbook methods for solving ordinary differential equations? Calculus and elementary differential equations but not Fourier series or vector calculus or advanced calculus? An upper undergraduate course in ["mathematics for scientists and engineers"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470458364) but no differential geometry?

Comment: I have edited the question to bring more clarity to the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a little strange to start with Copernicus if the interplay with geometry is really the focus, but try [Linton, From Eudoxus to Einstein: a History of Mathematical Astronomy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/From_Eudoxus_to_Einstein/aJuwFLGWKF8C?hl=en&gbpv=0), and [Kline, Mathematics: a Cultural Approach](https://vdoc.pub/documents/mathematics-a-cultural-approach-addison-wesley-series-in-mathematics-5i1387vq2e90) (has chapters on Copernican revolution, on advances in analytic and differential geometry, and on gravity).

Comment: Will try. Thank you..

Comment: I advise you the following exceptional book: ["The history and practice of Ancient astronomy"](https://www.amazon.com/History-Practice-Ancient-Astronomy/dp/0195095391) by James Evans, but it stops at Kepler (including him). I had never seen before such a clarity in explanations, sustended by very clear "geometric" illustrations, ideal as a reference for students.